# Bootstrap Container Fluid for xs, sm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'd like my outer-most div container to be just "container" for md and lg, but container-fluid for xs and sm. Can I achieve this natively? Do I need some additonal CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update 2020:**

As of Bootstrap 4.4, there are now [responsive containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#responsive):

```
<div class="container-sm">100% wide until small breakpoint</div>
<div class="container-md">100% wide until medium breakpoint</div>
<div class="container-lg">100% wide until large breakpoint</div>
<div class="container-xl">100% wide until extra large breakpoint</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/C8GAvbW1yA)

**Original answer:**

The `container` and `container-fluid` are identical on the `xs` breakpoint since they're both full width. To override the width for the `sm` breakpoint you could do this..

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
   .container {
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

[Demo](http://codeply.com/go/dHFw0LcVPl)

Comment: Here it is !
Bootstrap 4.4 has ```.container-md``` class you need.
Container is fluid below 768px, and with margin above.

See the doc : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#containers

Comment: I did this `/* // Small devices (landscape phones, 414px and up) */
@media (min-width: 414px) { 
    .card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
    .container {
      max-width: 95%;
    }
}`

Answer (score 27):

**With Bootstrap 4**
Plain css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
  }
}
```

If you use Sass:

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
  }
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/albertojacini/pen/KXgNqB

Comment: You should use media-breakpoint-down(sm) because he asks for xs and sm, not md

Comment: This is the best method, do not mess with the vendor files. works well with Laravel app.scss as well...

Answer (score 10):

> As noted, this is solution for Bootstrap 4

### The Issue

Currently we have a full-width edge-to-edge fluid container for `xs` viewport. Then we have fixed size containers for `sm`, `md`, `lg` etc.

As `sm` viewport is also considered as a small device sometimes we would want to have full-width edge-to-edge fluid container there too, the same as for `xs`.

### The Solution

If you compile Bootstrap from SCSS by yourself then you can simply override the variable `$container-max-widths` by removing `max-width` for `sm` breakpoint. **This is a neat and clean solution** I would recommend.

Find in the Bootstrap source code (vendor) `_variables.scss`:

```
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px, // <-- we are going to remove this line
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
) !default;
```

Copy into your custom file and override by removing `sm` definition row and removing `!default` keyword  e.g. in `_my-variables.scss` file:

```
$container-max-widths: (
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
);
```

Learn more about [Theming Bootstrap with your own SCSS variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/).

*If you do not compile Bootstrap by yourself then you definitively might want to. It's the whole new level of magic you'll find there.*

Comment: Yes, this is the best way for sass, I usually remove sm, md, lg.

Comment: This is ok if you only have one .container. If you have more and you want treat them differently, you should stick with @Alberto Jacini solution.

Comment: Well @aProgger if you have more containers and if you treat them differently then obviously you are doing something wrong and not the way bootstrap is meant to be used. Containers are there only to offset the rows and bootsrap offers only one gutter size so there should be no need for different containers than those which bootstrap has set for you. Unless you have containers that has nothing to do with bootstrap, but then this is irrelevant to my answer.

Comment: @Hrvoje Golcic Maybe I get you wrong but what is wrong with having a .container followed by a .container-fluid followed by .container? I did not mean nesting them.

Comment: @aProgger Nothing is wrong with that but if you use .container-fluid then you don't have the issue addressed in this topic whatsoever and you don't need to put width:100% because this one already is 100% in all viewports

Comment: @Hrvoje Golcic That was just an example of how a structure of multiple .container(s) could look like. I know a fluid container has 100% width. And I never wanted to address the topic but your answer. One get certainly problems, if the container-max-widths are altered because they apply on ever .container. I just wanted to hint on that and others can keep that in mind. For the most people its clear anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this solution (y)

Answer (score 1):

If using Angular you can use ngClass with a ternary and have a function return true if window is less that the pixel breakpoint for lg?

**main.component.html:**

```
<div [ngClass]="isFluid() ? 'container-fluid' : 'container'">
      --your content--
</div>
```

**main.component.ts:**

```
isFluid() {
    return $(window).width() < 960;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4(.4) has it natively:

> `.container`, which sets a max-width at each responsive breakpoint
>
> `.container-fluid`, which is width: 100% at all breakpoints
>
> `.container-{breakpoint}`, which is width: 100% until the specified

so, in your case, you can set:

```
<div class="container-md">
```

to achieve container at 100% width for xs and sm (fluid), and partial width above it

References: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/